# POST JSON to ASP.NET MVC5? (NOT web API)

Tags: json, post, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

Is there a way to POST a JSON data to an MVC5 action? **Not a WebAPI!**

The problem is: my action gets called, but all properties of incoming model are null.

Model:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

[JsonObject()]
[Serializable()]
public class DemoModel
{
    [JsonProperty()]
    public string a { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty()]
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

Action is:

```
[HttpPost()]
public ActionResult demoaction(DemoModel model)
{
    //model.a here is null, should be "AAA"
    //model.b here is null, should be "BBB"
}
```

I have been using Fiddler to simulate the request. My POST request looks like this:

```
POST http://localhost:9000/demoaction HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:9000
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 60
```

And the body looks like this:

```
{"a":"AAA","b":"BBB"}
```

So, the question again: how can I POST the JSON to an action? In my case all the properties of the model are null.

Comment: FromBody attribute is not available in non WebAPI :/

Comment: You are correct. my apologies

Answer (score 0):

I just use these codes and it worked fine on MVC5 action
but be sure you are using `Content-Type : application/json` in your POST request header without that it will not work correctly and model will still null

```
public class DemoModel
    {

        public string a { get; set; }


        public string b { get; set; }
    }

[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(DemoModel model)
        {

            return View();
        }
```